# Game crashes after I open a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Whenever I open a MC world, the game waits for a few seconds before closing. It waited long enough for me to walk around a little, but then it would crash. here is the crash report:

[image: Crash log]

Comment: Is your Java up to date?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?  Have you deleted / reinstalled Minecraft?

Comment: @Studoku those are 2 completely different errors due to having completely different problematic frames.

Comment: Try getting the newest Java version

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by outdated or broken Intel graphics card drivers. Update them here: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/